# Error on [order by] in SQL Server CE

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, sql-server-ce

I have a `.sdf` database file with a table `tblOrderLine`. When I use `order by` I get an error, when I remove the `order by` it is working fine. Any help would be appreciated.

The error:

> SqlCeException was caught There was an error parsing the query.
>   [Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 80,Token in error = order by]

My SQL code:

```
SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand("(Select LineID, OrderID, ItemName, Code from [tblOrderLine] where Code=@code [order by] tblOrderLine.LineID desc)", con);
com.Parameters.Add("@code", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = code;
```

Comment: Remove square brackets (`[]`) of Order by

Comment: with out brackets error: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 78,Token in error = order ]

Comment: I am not sure for `.sdf` but you should remove brackets around your query as well   `new SqlCeCommand("Select LineID, OrderID, ItemName, Code from [tblOrderLine] where Code=@code order by tblOrderLine.LineID desc", con);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You should not use the Square brackets for keywords other than
>   **database objects**.

Remove `[]` for the keyword **order by**.

**Update**

```
SqlCeCommand com = new SqlCeCommand(@"Select LineID, OrderID, ItemName, Code from [tblOrderLine] where Code=@code order by tblOrderLine.LineID desc", con);
```

Try this

Comment: with out brackets error: There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 78,Token in error = order ]

Comment: @PlazzaSele updated the answer, paste the exact query. i have replaced the brackets used. `()`

Comment: it is working now. thank you. can you please explain what is the difference betweet @"select... and "select..

Comment: no removing brackets with in your "(select * from table)" is enough. But using `@` ignores newline, spaces within your query. read more about string literal https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(v=vs.71).aspx